# Error message after rebooting

Tags: 14.04, usb

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in a Acer Aspire M5. Every time I reboot after I get the Acer logo, I get the following:

```
The disk drive for Xmnt/usb-Memorex_Travel_Drive_CL_07A50403BE24FFAF-0:0 is not ready or not present.

Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.
```

I have been pressing S for the past few weeks, and then my box will boot up normally. However, I would prefer of course to not have to do this at all every time my machine goes for reboot.

Can anyone please help me here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an entry in file `/etc/fstab` that tells ubuntu to mount a device - most likely a USB stick. The stick is not there and ubuntu is trying to tell you that it can't do what fstab told it to do.

Edit that file and comment out that entry (put # to the left of the line). Then reboot and see if the problem has been fixed.

I also find it a bit odd to see `Xmnt/`. Normally it is `/mnt/`.